# Python3.6 over python 3.4

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I have both `python2.7`, `python3.4` and `python3.6` installed on my Debian Jessie GNU Linux desktop and want to make python3.6 the default python3 when I run on terminal or using `IDLE`.
How do I do it?

Comment: this article may help https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux

Comment: Make an alias: `alias python3="python3.6"`. By putting this in your `.bashrc` file it will be available for each terminal you open. Your IDE probably offers its own ways for configuring an interpreter (on a per project basis). Alternatively you can replace the original symlink. Check its location via `which python3` (probably `/usr/bin/python3`) and via `ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3` you can update that symlink.

Comment: Alias helps while running on terminal, however it still don't solve the IDLE problem. Tried lots of alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem too. What I did was I went into my home directory and made a file called `.bash_profile` and put the following line into it.

```
alias python=/usr/bin/python3.6
```

Then I saved the file, restarted my ssh connection and its good. Please note that this only changes the python version used during calls from your ssh session.

If you have a script written in python or something else that calls `python ...` then it will get the "default" python version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

to check your currect version:

```
python --version
```

to change it:

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.4
```